# Authorisation Header and Content Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a code in C# to build the console to implement get request.
We were using POSTMAN to achieve the task but we decided to build our own.

I need to pass the user name and pw in headers of the request.
Since i am new to programming,can you guide me.

I have written below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object response;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetRequest("https://www.google.com");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        async static void GetRequest(string url)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)) 
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: what is the URL...did it work on postman.. where are you setting the headers and application type in HttpClient ??

Comment: It would have been great if you took the time to search for the answer instead of asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

DefaultRequestHeaders is not working, I have used below snippet for authentication

```
string _ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
var _CredentialBase64 = "xxxxxxxxx=";
httpWebRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", _CredentialBase64));
```